# Unable to display record fetched from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I use the below code to fetch a particular record from sqlite.

```
public String getDetails(long phone) throws SQLException{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {NAME, AGE, AREA, PHONE, SEX}, PHONE + "=" + phone, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(mCursor != null){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    String result = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NAME));
    return result;
}
```

And I am calling this method from another class with the below code

```
dbAdapterExisting.read();
String temp = dbAdapterExisting.getDetails(mobile);
dbAdapterExisting.close();
textViewExistingName.setText(temp);
```

The record is getting fetched and am able to display the 'name' field in textview, but how do i fetch all the fields i.e 'age', 'area', 'sex' and show it on different textviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `getDetails()` method only returns a single string, and you want to fetch multiple items, you need to change some things.  `Maps` are good data structures for returning data this way.  For example:

```
public Map<String, Object> getDetails(long phone) throws SQLException{

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {NAME, AGE, AREA, PHONE, SEX}, PHONE + "=" + phone, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(mCursor != null){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NAME));
    map.put(NAME, name);
    String age = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AGE));
    map.put(AGE, age);
    String area = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AREA));
    map.put(AREA, area);
    map.put(PHONE, phone);
    String sex = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(SEX));
    map.put(SEX, sex);

    return map;
```

}

Then, in your calling code switch to using the Map returned instead:

```
Map<String, Object> temp = dbAdapterExisting.getDetails(mobile);
// get the name:
String name = temp.get(dbAdapterExisting.NAME);
// etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as the following.
I will show an example getting sex.

```
String sex = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(SEX));
```

Just as you did.
For getting a float, double, integer value you use
mCursor.getFloat/Double/Integer

Comment: thanks, but as I was fetching multiple things, the below help provided by Chris worked perfectly.